# Is it OK to use __doPostBack()?

Tags: asp.net, dopostback

Is it OK to use `__doPostBack()` or it is not recommended because it is generated from ASP.Net and we are not sure if they changed it in a next version of ASP.Net.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would advice against it, since it's internal stuff of `ASP.NET` and was never meant to be used directly.

Instead, what I'm doing when I need to "manually" trigger PostBack is adding hidden "server side" button with the proper OnClick:

```
<asp:Button id="btnDummy" runat="server" OnClick="Foo" style="display: none;" />
```

Then the JS is:

```
document.getElementById("<%=btnDummy.ClientID%>").click();
```

This way I don't care **how** post back happens, I just trigger the natural flow of events.

Answer (score 9):

You should not call it directly. You should *generate* the javascript call by using functions in `Page.ClientScript` such as:

- [GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx)
- [GetPostBackClientHyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackclienthyperlink.aspx)

This will ensure that it's always compatible.

Answer (score 1):

They probably won't change it, but why call it directly?
I think it's a better strategy to trigger the event (a button click for example) and let the control trigger the postback.

I you do need to trigger the postback directly it's recommended to use the Page.ClientScript functions tenfour described.

Answer (score 1):

I think its perfectly fine to use directly, and have used it without fail, its just a javascript function after all.

Comment: Yes, it's "just a javascript function", but the problem is that there is no *guarantee* that it will be present in a next version.

Answer (score 0):

We use it all over the place and I can't imagine it would ever be stripped out of ASP.NET.  I think the fake/hidden button method is just as hokie if not worse.  If you use the fake button approach, then you get no option to pass in the __EVENTARGUMENT.  I like using __EVENTARGUMENT to pass my data to the server better than creating hidden fields, because it would be more difficult for a hacker to compromise than simply posting back some hidden field to my page.  I also don't like the idea of creating fields and controls on the page if they are not even going to be displayed.  I am sure that the fake button approach is probably easier for a newbie coder to understand.  That being said I am searching for a more elegant way to approach this, but still find myself calling

```
    __doPostBack('%=UpdatePanel.ClientID%>','MyData')
```

in some cases.