# ASP.Net dropdownlist post back on lose focus?

Tags: asp.net, events, drop-down-menu, lost-focus

Right now I'm using the OnSelectedIndexChanged event to trigger a post back and update some other fields in the form. That works fine. But I would like it to do the post back when the drop down list loses focus, rather than on every change. The problem is, when someone selects the list, then types a number, it will change with every key stroke they press, and that will trigger the post back *before* they get to the value they are trying to type.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
ddlDropDown.Attributes.Add("onblur", "__doPostBack('ddlDropDown','');");
```

I have not tested it, but I believe it will work - or I hope.

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript event for something losing focus is called `onblur`.

Use `Attributes.Add()` in server-side code to add the function name to be called. You can then trigger the postback from said function.

Comment: I don't want to run javascript, I want to run server side code onblur. Can I use javascript to trigger the post back?

Comment: Yes, in fact ASP.NET uses JavaScript to trigger postbacks already, you just don't write it explicitly so it isn't immediately obvious. You can either call it yourself (a bit quick & dirty), or trigger a hidden control to do the postback 'naturally'. Take a look at [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448825/is-it-ok-to-use-dopostback).